# Jquery / Ajax dialog box where select between all the rows of a sql table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

in my CMS, I have a big table which is stored in all the client companies. In the `Position` table I want to store the `id` of the client.

I have the `addPosition` page that have to permit to insert such `id` selecting the client name.
The way I thought to develop it, is to popup a dialog from which select from the entire list of clients and the result of the dialog should be then stored in a hidden field (for example).

Is it possible to use  jQuery or ajax? If yes, how? If no, which is a good workaround (or maybe a better solution) of the problem?

P.S. The PHP  part shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Are you saying you want to know the best way to assign a position to a client?

Comment: you can use Jquery's ajax itself,

Comment: I solved the problem in a different way: I used a javascript  autocompleter instead of a dialog box, using the name of the company and attaching the clientId too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to do an AJAX request in jQuery, this is one way:

HTML:

```
<div id="message" style="display:none"></div>

<form action="script.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    <select name="employees">
        <option value="1">Joh Smith</option>
        <option value="2">Janeh Doe</option>    
    </select>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $this.attr('action'),
        type: $this.attr('method'),
        data: $this.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
                $('#message')
                    .text('Database updated successfully')
                    .addClass('success')
                    .show();
            }
            else {
                $('#message')
                    .text('Error happened, AJAX request completed but PHP had a problem.')
                    .addClass('error')
                    .show();
            }            
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error happened, AJAX request could not be completed.');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

In PHP if your database was updated successfully:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => true
));
```

otherwise:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => false
));
```